# Exchange 2003 - SMTP from address not matching Active Directory

Tags: exchange, smtp, outlook, smtp-headers

Is there a way to configure Exchange so that clients that do NOT use native exchange connector (Osx mail, or outlook configured as POP) get the sender name information from the Active directory?

Example: I create a user and in AD I set his display name to: John Smith M.D.

The user configures his OSx Mail so that his user name is "Crazy Jonnhy"... When he sends an email the recipient sees it´s from Crazy Johnny and not "John Smith M.D."

Is there a way to override the header sent from the email client and set the sender´s name to what´s found under AD?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do it automatically as part of the product, however this article http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/compliance-policies-archiving/exchange-2007/2003-address-rewrite-feature.html provides a means of putting in a rule to handle the rewrites.